# Normal rotation of several points vs rotation in "phase" space

Tags: rotations

Suppose I have rigid body of $N$ points in 3D space. I can rotate this body as a whole in that 3D space.

Now suppose I took all coordinates of all points and put them into single $3N$ dimensional vector. Is it a point in "phase" space. And I also can rotate this point in that phase space.

Are these two types of rotations form a single family of things? Can I formulate all rotations of this family in single mathematical manner?

Comment: Sure, the second type is produced by block diagonal matrices with $N$ identical blocks $3\times3$.

Comment: The term "phase space" normally refers to the combination of position and velocity in a 6D space.

Comment: @Tpofofn this is why I used quotes. How would you name this spece here correctly?